# PHP: readfile() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, security

I wrote a php script which outputs html files on the screen which uses readfile($htmlFile);
however in the web-hosting that I have purchased the readfile() has been disabled for security reasons.
Is there any substitution ( other php functions) for the readfile() or I have no choice but to ask the admin to enable it for me?

Thanks

Comment: move hosts, they are clearly not a good one, who knows what else they have disabled.

Comment: That sounds like an odd thing to disable - it's usually the system() calls that get disabled for security reasons. What sort of installation is it? That's not normal for cPanel (a popular Linux shared hosting system) as far as I know.

Comment: Btw, yes get in touch with the host - and ask them for a full list of disabled functions and paste them here. Someone will give you a view as to whether they're reasonable (though it is perfectly possible to run shared hosting with nothing disabled, afaik).

Comment: Here are the list of functions disabled: allow_url_fopen, escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd, ini_alter, passthru, popen, proc_open, proc_close, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_nice, readfile, show_source, system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check which functions are disabled by using:

```
var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions'));
```

---

You can try to use fopen() and fread() instead:

http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

```
$file = fopen($filename, 'rb');
if ( $file !== false ) {
    while ( !feof($file) ) {
        echo fread($file, 4096);
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

---

Or fopen() with fpassthru()

```
$file = fopen($filename, 'rb');
if ( $file !== false ) {
    fpassthru($file);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Alternatively you can use fwrite() to write content.

---

You can also try to use file_get_contents()

http://nl2.php.net/file_get_contents

Or you can use file()

http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

I wouldn't recommend  this method though, but if nothing works...

```
$data = file($filename);
if ( $data !== false ) {
    echo implode('', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If its disabled then you could do something like following as alternative:

```
$file = fopen($yourFileNameHere, 'rb');
if ( $file !== false ) {
    while ( !feof($file) ) {
        echo fread($file, 4096);
    }
    fclose($file);
}

//OR
$contents = file_get_contents($yourFileNameHere); //if for smaller files
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
$path = '/some/path/to/file.html';
$file_string = '';
$file_content = file($path);
// here is the loop
foreach ($file_content as $row) {
     $file_string .= $row;
}

// finally print it
echo $file_string;
```